# show twitter live feeds in tableau dash-board

Tags: twitter, tableau-api

our requirement is like we want to showcase the Twitter live feeds(Timeline Post) in tableau dash-board. we had tried many things but its not give us the live post from twitter.

We try to embed the link generated from twitter that doesn't show me the the image or anything, same with if URL as well

can anyone provide me any help regrading this

Comment: You would have to use a Web Data Connector.  Details are here: http://tabvizexplorer.com/twitter-api-wdc-for-tableau/

Comment: this not fullfill my requirement as its not showing me live Timeline post.